# After upgrading PrimeFaces 3.5 to 4.0, p:fileUpload throws exception

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a code that make the upload perfectly using primefaces 3.5, but I update the primefaces lib in my project to 4.0 and it doesn´t work any more. Here is the code:

web.xml

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class> org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>
```

xhtml page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{siteBean.fileUploadAction}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

SiteBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SiteBean{
public void fileUploadAction(FileUploadEvent event) {
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        FacesContext aFacesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext context = (ServletContext) aFacesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();

        String realPath = context.getRealPath("/");

        File folder = new File(realPath + "/img/sites/");
        folder.mkdirs();

        byte[] file = event.getFile().getContents();
        String path = realPath + "/img/sites/" + event.getFile().getFileName();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fos.write(file);
        fos.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

When I try to upload a file it shows me exception message. 
Here is the exception:

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:305)
at managedBean.SiteBean.fileUploadAction(SiteBean.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:290)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
at    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)  
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at         org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at  org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
```

I´m using Netbeans 7.4, primefaces 4.0, common io 2.4, common file upload 1.3 and jsf 2.2.

Comment: Post the exception message ;)

Comment: Exception messageis: Error: null

Comment: Post the full stack trace, not just one line

Answer (score 1):

The datas are in the inputStream

Try something like this :

```
// write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
OutputStream out = null;
InputStream in = event.getFile().getInputStream();          
try 
{           
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirPath, fileName));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) 
    {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();

} catch (IOException e) {

}
 finally
{
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome Vanilson, could you mark the answer as valid please ?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green